# PL/SQL - Varchar as search argument?

Tags: search, plsql, arguments, varchar

I have the following issue:

I have this table:

```
MyUser(
ID Number,
Name Varchar2,
Username Varchar2,
Password Varchar2,
etc)
```

If I run the `Select * from MyUser;` statement I get all the rows of the table.
However if I run this statement `Select * from MyUser where Username = 'someUsername';` I don't get any rows at all. (Yes, I've made sure I have a row with a username 'someUsername').

Comment: `Yes, I've made sure I have a row with a username 'someUsername'` No you have not. The query result clearly shows that you don't have `someUsername` string in the database. You might have a typo, unexpected whitespace, non-matching capitalization or non-matching character sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MYUSER
  WHERE UPPER(USERNAME) LIKE '%SOMEUSERNAME%'
```

Share and enjoy.